# Why we use git remote add origin for the first time?

Tags: git, gitlab

After I create a folder with some files, and I want to push them, I need to make it in this order

```
git remote add origin "github repo link"
git push origin master
```

And it is successfull.But after my first push,
and some changes to the file then the pushing works with only
`git push origin master`

Why i need `git remote add origin "github repo link"`
for the first time?

Comment: Because configuration changes are persisted in a file...

Comment: Can you please be more specific

Comment: Read about [working with remote repositories](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) in the [Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a local Git repository. This repository has various settings, persisted in its configuration file. If you add a remote, this is written to the file `.git/config` in your repository:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/foo/bar
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Now for the next push or fetch this remote is remembered.

See [10.5 Git Internals - The Refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) for documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: because once you add a remote repository to your project, each operation working with that remote knows the link to that remote already. Now what that means, is when you do a `git push origin master`, you are saying to git:
"Look git, I want to push the current branch I am on to the remote repository named `origin`, and I want to push to the `master` branch in that remote."

When you execute the command

`git remote add origin "github repo link"`

you are saying that for the current project, there is a remote repository with the name `origin`, with the address of `"github repo link"`. You don't have to repeat that step every time, since this information is saved locally in your git project. Every time you do an operation that specifies `origin`, git will know which URL to look for.

This means that for one project you can have *many* remote repos. But for each remote, you have to have a separate name.